# Static column in Union operation is not giving correct value

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have written the below query in Oracle:

```
(SELECT 'A' AS COST_POOL_#,FCCV_A.COST_CENTER, COST_CENTER_SHORT_NAME,COST_POOL as COST_POOL_A,COST_POOL_PER as COST_POOL_A_PER,
COST_SUB_POOL_A,DRIVER,DRIVER_PER,MARKUP_PERCENTAGE,MARKUP_BASE,PRICING FROM
FD_COST_CENTER_VALIDATION 
FCCV_A JOIN (SELECT COST_CENTER, MAX(S_ROWID) S_ROWID from FD_COST_CENTER_VALIDATION GROUP BY COST_CENTER) 
FCCV_B ON FCCV_A.COST_CENTER = FCCV_B.COST_CENTER AND FCCV_A.S_ROWID = FCCV_B.S_ROWID)
UNION
(SELECT 'B' AS COST_POOL_#,FCCV_A.COST_CENTER, COST_CENTER_SHORT_NAME,COST_POOL_B,COST_POOL_B_PER,COST_SUB_POOL_B,DRIVER_2,DRIVER_2_PER,MARKUP_PERCENTAGE_2,
MARKUP_BASE_2,PRICING_2 FROM
FD_COST_CENTER_VALIDATION 
FCCV_A JOIN (SELECT COST_CENTER, MAX(S_ROWID) S_ROWID from FD_COST_CENTER_VALIDATION GROUP BY COST_CENTER) 
FCCV_B ON FCCV_A.COST_CENTER = FCCV_B.COST_CENTER AND FCCV_A.S_ROWID = FCCV_B.S_ROWID)
```

I want the resultset from the first query to have the first column have "A" in all the records and the first column in second resultset of the UNION should have "B" in all the records, but after execution it is not giving "B" in any of the records; all the records have "A" in the first column. Please let me know as to what I should change so that I can get "B" in the result set from the second query.

Comment: What happens if you do just the second select alone?

Comment: I can see "B" in the first column as expected but when I do Union it is all "A"

Comment: If you have atleast one row in `second query` then you should see atleast one `'B'` in first column

Comment: I just now realized-it is becoming a cartisian product-which is not what i want, what should i do to avoid the cartisian product?

Comment: One question at a time. NoDisplayName is correct; if the second query produces results, they must be visible with UNION also. I guess you didn't look properly. Use UNION ALL instead, so the B rows should be at the end and look again.

Comment: As to the cartisian product: I see none. Your joins cannot produce cartesian products, as cost_center and s_rowid are unique in your derived tables and you use both as join criteria. I am pretty sure you are mistaken here.

Comment: thanks for all your help, i can get what i want

Comment: Is your question solved, could you clarify please